# Ie8-canvas tags take effect only once in a html

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-8

I try to create two piechart in one html page:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 placeholder" >
    <div style="margin:0 auto"><canvas id="zftChart" width="320px" height="200px" ></canvas></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6  placeholder" >
    <div style="margin:0 auto"><canvas id="bocomChart" width="320px" height="200px" ></canvas></div>
</div>
```

But only the first `<canvas>` take effect.
[In IE8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE8NA.png)  [In Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDuCC.png)

If i delete the first `<canvas>` the second will take effect.

In console it shows object not support getContext. But when I delete the second `<canvas>` it won't show.
I have uesed `window.onload = function() {}`to cover my code.
And I have included js packages such as html5shiv.js excanvas.js to enable `<canvas>`

Comment: IE8 didn't support canvas API, are you using some polyfill?

Comment: I have included js packages such as `html5shiv.js` `excanvas.js` to support.

Comment: That would be good to add it to an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it. I delete px from `<canvas>` like this:
`<canvas id="zftChart" width="320" height="200" ></canvas>`
But I still don't know why this problem cause...